# ordering names in strings and summarise the order numbers

Tags: r

I am working with two tibbles. The result should be a third tibble. The first tibble (order) defines the order of the names. This order should be applied on the second tibble (df).

```
order <- tibble(order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                names = c("Christine", "Bernward", "Daniel", "Atze", "Franz", "Emil"))
print(order)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  order names    
  <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 Christine
2     2 Bernward 
3     3 Daniel   
4     4 Atze     
5     5 Franz    
6     6 Emil

df <- tibble(names_combined = c("Atze, Christine", "Bernward, Christine",
                                "Emil, Daniel", "Atze, Franz", "Franz, Bernward, Christine"))
print(df)
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  names_combined     
  <chr>              
1 Atze, Christine    
2 Bernward, Christine
3 Emil, Daniel       
4 Atze, Franz        
5 Franz, Bernward, Christine
```

As you can see, the first value in df is "Atze, Christine", but it should be "Christine, Atze", since Christine is ordered at number one and Atze at number four. This should be applied for all values in the tibble df. It is important, that the structure is kept. So it should be "name1, name2" with komma and space separating them.

As a second column the numbers of the order should be summed up for each combination. So Christine as 1 and Atze as 4 should be 5 and so on.

The result should look like this:

```
result <- tibble(names_combined = c("Christine, Atze", "Christine, Bernward",
                                    "Daniel, Emil", "Atze, Franz", "Christine, Bernward, Franz"),
                 order_combined = c(5, 3, 9, 9, 8))
print(result)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  names_combined             order_combined
  <chr>                               <dbl>
1 Christine, Atze                         5
2 Christine, Bernward                     3
3 Daniel, Emil                            9
4 Atze, Franz                             9
5 Christine, Bernward, Franz              8
```

I was thinking of an approach like splitting the names_combined in df into its elements and then combining them freshly with the order but that seems too difficult. Maybe there is a more straight forward solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input data 'df', create a sequence column with `row_number()`), split the 'names_combined' with `separate_rows` (from `tidyr`), do a `left_join` with the 'order' dataset, `arrange` the rows with 'rn', and 'order' column, then grouped by 'rn', `paste` the 'names_combined' with `toString` while getting the `sum` or 'order' column in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(names_combined) %>%
  left_join(order, by = c("names_combined" = "names")) %>% 
   arrange(rn, order) %>%
   group_by(rn) %>%
   summarise(names_combined = toString(names_combined), 
         order_combined = sum(order), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  names_combined             order_combined
#  <chr>                               <dbl>
#1 Christine, Atze                         5
#2 Christine, Bernward                     3
#3 Daniel, Emil                            9
#4 Atze, Franz                             9
#5 Christine, Bernward, Franz              8
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R approach by splitting the string and matching it with `order` dataframe.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(df$names_combined, ',\\s*'), function(x) {
  ind <- match(x, order$names)
  data.frame(names_combined = toString(x[order(ind)]), 
             order_combined = sum(order$order[ind]))
}))

#              names_combined order_combined
#1            Christine, Atze              5
#2        Christine, Bernward              3
#3               Daniel, Emil              9
#4                Atze, Franz              9
#5 Christine, Bernward, Franz              8
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I made it. In order to improve my coding skills I tried a solution for myself. Akrun's solution was a guideline and is undoubtedly more elegant and more efficient. With my skills I come to this solution:
I have used `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr`

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  data.frame(str_split(df$names_combined, ", ", simplify = TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X"), values_to = "names") %>% 
  left_join(order, by = "names") %>% 
  mutate(id = rep(row_number(), each=3, length.out = n())) %>%  
  group_by(id) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  arrange(order) %>% 
  summarize(names_combined = str_c(names, collapse = ", "), 
            order_combined = sum(order))%>% 
  select(-id)

# Output:
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  names_combined             order_combined
  <chr>                               <dbl>
1 Christine, Atze                         5
2 Christine, Bernward                     3
3 Daniel, Emil                            9
4 Atze, Franz                             9
5 Christine, Bernward, Franz              8
```